# returning a Java InputStream from the model layer in MVC

Tags: java, servlets, model-view-controller, jdbc, inputstream

I'm creating an MVC web application where a user downloads a 100mb+ file. The file is stored in chunks across a number of BLOB in an Oracle database.

Suppose you have a class in your Model named `File`, and an `HttpServlet` class `FileController`.

In File, we have a method to get a stream to read the file from. It's coded like this...

```
    ArrayList<InputStream> blobStreams = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
    try
    {
        //<set up and execute JDBC query here> 

        while (results.next())
        {
            blobStreams.add(results.getBinaryStream("blob"));
        }
        return new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(blobStreams));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //<exception handling>
    }
    finally
    {
        try{if (results!=null)results.close(); }catch(Exception e){};
        try{if (statement!=null) statement.close();}catch(Exception e){};
        try{if (connection!=null) connection.close();}catch(Exception e){};
    }
```

In `FileController` in our `doGet(...)` method we write from the stream `fileContents` as follows.

```
                final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int length;
                while ((length = fileContents.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    response.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
```

I am encountering an exception, "*java.io.IOException: Closed Connection*" presumably because the JDBC objects are closed in the `finally` block of `File`.

What's the best MVC way to return a stream without it being closed prematurely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning input streams from the service tier, can you pass the output stream into the method and have the service tier handle the streaming?

Something like this:

```
public void getBlobs(OutputStream stream);
```

That way the service itself can handle the output and correctly close connections once the data has been streamed, it also means the consumer of the service doesn't need to worry about buffering the data correctly.